# Prep for installing sub panel in attached garage

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I recently built a three car garage attached to the side of my house with a slab on grade foundation. It replaced an earlier single car garage built in the 1920s that was detached and about 15' from the house.

I used the existing 30amp circuit that went to that building to set up lights and a few outlets in the new garage. The house is 150 year old farm house which I had upgraded from a 60amp main service to 100amp when I bought the house 25 years ago. Later this year (probably fall), I would like to upgrade to a 200amp main service with a 70amp sub panel in the garage. The two biggest loads in there now are a 120v mig welder and a small portable compressor. I want the 70 amp sub panel to enable me to upgrade to a large 220v compressor in the future.

The main service panel is in the front corner of the main house basement which has a full basement and is 20' by 20'. Attached to the side of the main house is a kitchen ell that was built in the 1920s that is 20' feet wide with a 3' deep dirt floor crawl space. The foundation walls for main house and kitchen ell is granite block. Attached to the end of the kitchen is another 10' wide addition that was an old attached carriage house which I poured a slab on grade foundation that at it's top is basically level with the dirt floor of the crawl space. This last addition has a small bedroom in the back and a laundry room/hallway in the front that leads out to the attached garage. The slab for the attached garage is level with the slab in the laundry room. There is a 30" wide hallway in this last addition against the side of the kitchen with two steps down into the laundry room and through a doorway two steps down into the back bedroom. The current electric and plumbing for the laundry room and garage run under this hallway and then against the back wall of the laundry room that separates it from the back bedroom. I am in the process of remodeling the back bedroom and needed to remove the staircase to re-frame it. Before I button this up with the new staircase, it gives me access to the 2' high (slab to bottom of joist) crawl space below the little hallway. So now that you have all the background, here are the questions.

The length of the circuit wire from the main panel to the attached garage should be a little under 75' (including bends). I am thinking that the wire to feed the sub panel could be #6 4 shielded wire run along the top of the joists in the cellar of the main house and kitchen, and that it would be best to have that wire run all the way to the sub panel with no connections in the middle. I will drill a hole through the 6"x6" kitchen mud sill to feed the wire into the small hallway continuing on into the laundry room.

So my question is where I will not have easy access to the little space below that hallway should I use PVC conduit (i.e. 1 1/2" schedule 40)?

If I was to run the wire up the face of the laundry room wall and across and through the wall to the garage, does that run need to be inside conduit? All the existing circuits for the laundry room are in conduit from just inside the kitchen ell to their outlets (220 dryer, 120 washer). If I need (or should) put conduit under that hallway I was thinking I should do it now (just install that section of conduit) before I close everything back up. I keep going back and forth on what I should do and figured I should ask some experts for advice. Thank You, Frank

Comment: What do you mean by "shielded wire"?

Comment: Can you *please* break this up into paragraphs? Extremely hard to read as is.

Comment: I gave up reading after what should have been the 2nd or maybe 3rd paragraph. Formatting is critical to good communication, and good communication is critical to getting you a good answer. Just click the [edit] button above, then reread your question as though you have no idea what you're talking about, because none of us do.

Comment: Sure you can upgrade to a 200 amp service on your garage. (Condense version needed)You can then feed the 100 amp existing house panel but I would plan on a 125a feeder as that will allow a #1 copper or 2/0 aluminum to be used. 2020 code may allow all feeders to be smaller but #6 is way two small. I would use the same 125a in the garage, why panels are cheap get extra wire do the house then the leftover wire is for the garage. The difference in cost is minimal for your garage. Yes you can feed 2ea 125amp panels from a 200 amp main service. 360 max bends without a pull point for the house sub.

Comment: Wiring not in conduit is subject to rodent-chewing.